# Multiple entries in a MySQL column in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a mysql database with companies that cover a certain postcode. I want users to be able to type in a complete postcode (zipcode) (eg SW1 1FT) and the query return all company names etc that cover the postcode (SW1)

my first table "members" will contain "ID", "Company_Name", "Phone_Number",and possibly "Postcodes_covered"

Now I understand that listing several postcodes under the Postcodes_covered column is big no no!  Can anyone offer any advise or can i just add SW1, SW2, SW3 etc to a single column under postcodes_covered? Taking into account that there are many many post code areas!

Or should I be adding a second table called postcodes which links to the members table? If so how would you go about linking a post code area eh "SW1" to the relevent members and what would the search query look like when someone enters a postcode in the search bar?

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate table with all the postcodes. Then you can use a wildcard to find all the matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM members m
JOIN postcodes p ON m.id = p.member_id
WHERE p.postcodes_covered LIKE 'SW1%'
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar! So I would have one table called members and one called postcodes if I was using this code when the user enters their postcode? Also if I had a separate table for postcodes could you suggest how I would lay that out? If I have each postcode in one column eg sw1 sw2 sw3 I would then add the member id from the members table into a new row in those columns if those are the areas that member covered and leave the other columns blank in that row? Would that be correct? Thank you in advance your advice really has helped me out!! Mark

Comment: Like I said, you should have a separate table with postcodes. It will have two columns, `member_id` and `postcodes_covered`. The `members` table shouldn't have anything about postcodes in it.

Comment: Ah sorry for being thick I find this a minefield!, so I can enter multiple postcodes in the second column then?